# Magnolia CMS 5.5.9 SoftLocking

Tags: java, locking, content-management-system, magnolia

i've got a Problem. I want to use the Softlocking module to determine if there is somebody already editing a page. With that information I want to decide if I want to open the CKeditor in edit or read only mode.

I have injected softLockingSuport (DefaultSoftLockingSupport from Module 2.6.2) bean into my RichTextFieldFactory where ckeditor is initialized but all I can do is a

```
public List getLocks(String username, String identifier)
```

My first question is why do I need to specify a username to get locks? I want to get all the locks for that page and not only the locks for one user.

I want to do something like this

```
    List locks = softLockingSupport.getLocks("path/to/page");
    int lockSize = locks.size();

    if (lockSize>1) //lock is obtained before ckeditor is initialised
    {
        config.setReadOnly(true);
    }
```

Is there a better way to determine if a page is edited by someone else or what am I missing?

Thanks in advance,
Reencode

Comment: Hi @reencode,
How did you solve this issue? I also have to find out if someone is editing a  specific page in the page editor subapp. I read your issue and was wondering if you could share your solution. Thanks in advance, Ana

Comment: Hi, as Jan answer states there was no way (at that time) to get the needed information from the api. So we just informed our content-editors to be careful and communicate where they are working. Concurrent editing is still an issue in our environment. Maybe ckeditor5 https://ckeditor.com/collaboration/real-time-collaborative-editing/ will bring a solution but I don't know.. Working on something completely different now...

Answer (score 0):

The API doesn't really expose the information you are looking for. Also in the soft locking concept as implemented by Magnolia, anyone opening page for editing is acquiring lock so that there could be multiple locks by multiple people for the same page. All you can do is register LockListener once someone opens page of interest and count the locks for yourself :(

And if you do so in the dialog, your log count would be updated only if someone opens said dialog ... otoh that might be ok, since ppl editing other components on the page will not mess up w/ content of your CK editor anyway.